# Atribuir data a uma var date no oracle

Tags: oracle

```
v_data date;

v_data := to_date(to_char('01/02/2020));
```

Essa abordagem não funciona. Como atribuo uma data a uma var date no oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `to_date` recebe dois parâmetro.

1. parâmetro é a data
2. formato da data

---

```
v_data := to_date('01022020', 'ddmmyyyy');
```

mais exemplos:

```
TO_DATE ('2003/07/09', 'aaaa / mm / dd') Resultado: valor da data de 9 de julho de 2003

TO_DATE ('070903', 'MMDDYY') Resultado: valor da data de 9 de julho de 2003

TO_DATE ('20020315', 'aaaammdd') Resultado: valor da data de 15 de março de 2002
```